# Excel List-Based Data Validation using js API

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

I developed an Excel add-in that allows users to get a list of folders from our internal system into Excel and use that information to populate some forms. I'm using data validation to make sure that the user will pick a folder name from a dropdown menu. That works fine for few values (less than ~200), however, some directories have more than 6,000 folders and Excel does not display all of them in the dropdown menu. I already checked all the variables related to this - they all carry the total amount of data. In other words, I'm sure I'm sending Excel a list with 6k values, but it only displays around 200. The documentation says it can carry around 32k, so I don't understand why this is happening.
Here's the code I'm using to validate the data:

```
var range = sheet.getRangeByIndexes(1, columnNumber - 1, rowLength, 1);
range.dataValidation.clear();
//list has lenght around 6000
var approvedListRule = {
  list: {
    inCellDropDown: true,
    source: list.join()
  }
};
range.dataValidation.rule = approvedListRule;
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: which platform do you hit the issue or all platforms like excel online/win32/mac have the same issue?

Comment: I tried with win32 and online excel with 6k string value in several cells, and put these values as list value, it can work fine. If you suspect it is related to size issue, can you repro it with excel directly, like put some strings in one columns to monitor the file names. If you can repro it with scriptlab, consider reporting the issue on the office-js and better share the repro excel files and gist.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rita. I noticed that this limitation actually exists in Excel - when you try to add values as a comma-separated list, it limits the input string - that seems to be happening with the API too. One possible solution to this would be to save that list to a temporary range of cells and add the data validation from there...